# About pooling layer in CNN for landmark detection purpose

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, pooling

I was reading about landmark detection using CNN from this [website](https://medium.com/datatype/deeplearning-ai-cnn-week-3-object-detection-ce86e6c648e). In landmark detection, the output is the x-y coordinate of the object that we look for.

In CNN, as far as I know, we use the pooling layer (avg or max pool) in order to make representations more invariant to small translations. When I thought about this and landmark detection together, it seems to me whether pooling (especially in the first layer) would harm the coordinate information we want to output.

I found some papers where they seek for coordinates of objects in an image using CNN. Some of them use the pooling layer at the first step of forward prop ([figure 4](https://www.mdpi.com/machines/machines-07-00025/article_deploy/html/images/machines-07-00025-g004.png) of [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1702/7/2/25/htm)).

I think the pooling can be harmful to that kind of problems (when we use it at the beginning) but studies show that it does not. At least, we can not say directly that it will harm. I can not understand.